# How to check mousedown event isn't on scroller in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
// Close the bubble when we click on the screen.
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
// if ain't right click
if(e.button != 2){
    // hide
    setTimeout("bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';", 500);
}
}, false);
```

My probem is that when the user tries to scroll with the browser scroller the
setTimeout takes effect. How do i check that the mousedown isn't in the scroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the button is left and make sure it's not a bubbling event, not just if it's not right. I'd suggest to also use a function in `setTimeout`, so:

```
// Close the bubble when we click on the screen.
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    // If it's a left click and the target is the current target
    if(e.button === 1 && e.target === e.currentTarget) {
        // hide
        setTimeout(function() {
            bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }, 500);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Still when i cick the scroller the bubble hides itself